# How to prove that a module is trivial by some weird conditions.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a nonzero ring and let $J\subset A$ denote the intersection of all maximal ileft ideals of $A$, suppose that $M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module such that $M=J\cdot M$(i.e., every element of $M$ can be written as a finite sum $a_1\cdot x_1+a_2\cdot x_2+...+a_n\cdot x_n$). Prove that $M=0$.

I used Zorn's lemma to prove that if $r\in J$, then r must be in every ideal of A.(else there is a maximal ideal that doesn't contain $r$.) But how do we use the condition $M$ is finitely generated?

Comment: Weird conditions??? -1 until you change the title in a more adequate one.

Answer (score 1):

This roughly speaking is Nakayama's lemma.

To prove it, take a set of generators $m_1, \ldots m_n$. Since $M = JM$, in particular we have $m_1 \in JM$, i.e. $m_1 = \sum a_i m_i$, for $a_i \in J$. Hence $$(1 - a_1) m_1 = \sum_{i \neq 1} a_i m_i$$and we note $(1-a_1)$ must be a unit (if it's in ideal $I$, so is $a_1$, so is 1), hence we can throw $m_1$ out of our generating set. Throwing them out one by one, we see that $M = 0$.

Comment: I don't get why $1-a_1$ must be a unit. would you please elaborate a little bit more?Thanks

Comment: haha yeah okay this is the only step where we use that $J$ is the intersection of all maximal left ideals. point is: consider the left ideal $(1 - a_1) = \{r(1 - a_1): r \in A\}$, the statement that is the whole ring implies that $(1 - a_1)$ is a unit, as for some $r$ we have $r(1 - a_1) = 1$. Now, if it's not the whole ring it's contained in some maximal left ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. So we have $1 - a_1 \in \mathfrak{m}$, $a_1 \in \mathfrak{m}$, and so $1 \in \mathfrak{m}$, since it's closed under addition!